# C++ style in emacs : greater-than-80 column exception to the default parentheses auto-indent behavior

Tags: emacs, styles, indentation

I have a long function declaration in C++ that I'm writing up in emacs. The indentation behavior with parenthesis doesn't make an exception for 80 columns and looks like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > doFooBarBlahBlah(const std::map<std::pair<unsigned, std::string>, FoobarType> fooArg1,
                                                   const std::map<std::pair<unsigned, std::string>, FoobarType> fooArg2) {
```

Moving the argument to the next line and auto-indenting results in:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > doFooBarBlahBlah(
                                                   const std::map<std::pair<unsigned, std::string>, FoobarType> fooArg1,
                                                   const std::map<std::pair<unsigned, std::string>, FoobarType> fooArg2) {
```

The google C++ style guide suggests:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > doFooBarBlahBlah(
    const std::map<std::pair<unsigned, std::string>, FoobarType> fooArg1,
    const std::map<std::pair<unsigned, std::string>, FoobarType> fooArg2) {
```

Is there an emacs extension to automate indentation in a way that respects this rule?

Comment: A couple of typedefs would make that code both narrow *and* readable. And more flexible as a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited to account for column length exception*
This will do the trick for you:

```lisp
(defun my-c-custom-settings ()
  (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro 'my-special-indent))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-custom-settings)

(defun my-special-indent (pair)
  (let* ((symbol (car pair))
         (offset (cdr pair))
         (regular-column (c-lineup-arglist-intro-after-paren symbol)))
    (if (> (save-excursion (+ (aref regular-column 0)
                              (- (progn (end-of-line) (current-column))
                                  (progn  (beginning-of-line) 
                                          (skip-chars-forward " \t")
                                          (current-column)))))
           80)
        '+
      regular-column)))
```

The way to find out what setting needs be set for indentation is to move your cursor to the point you want to indent differently and do:

```
M-x c-set-offset
```

aka <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>.  And in this case you want to set it to `'+` indicating to indent one more level than the current level.  One of the settings can be a function which returns the offset.

There's a ton of information available in the manual for cc-mode on [indentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Indentation-Engine-Basics.html),   including how to customize it (I took the easy way in the sample above).  As well as the documentation for [c-offsets-alist](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I actually prefer emacs's default if the line is short. I only want it to do this for long lines. I imagine it's probably not that easy to get emacs to do conditional indentation behavior like this...

Comment: @daj It's straightforward, I updated the answer to do what you want.